# Jquery GET in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I call `my_function` on form submit. The function looks inside a text file for the number entered by the user in `my_input`. If this number does not exist, the function pops an alert and should stop form submit.

My problem: the alert is shown, but when I close it, the form gets submitted. My problem is similar with this thread: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

One of the solutions there is to do the GET in plain javascript. Can someone help please? This is too advanced for me.

```js
function my_function() {
  $.get("http://www.example.com/file.txt", function(contents) {
    var my_number = document.getElementById("my_input").value;
    var hasString = contents.includes(my_number);
  });
  console.log(hasString); // **ALWAYS RETURNS UNDEFINED**
  if (hasString == false) {
    alert('Number does not exist in text file!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just asking for my particular code, how to do the get without jquery.

Comment: Have you tried one of the methods from the post you linked, specifically parts about letting functions accept callbacks as parameters?

Comment: The post you listed literally answers your question.

Comment: Do not have the know how. Was just hoping that somone will magically change the code for me :)

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on performing AJAX calls with plain Javascript.

Comment: I do not know how to transform this $.get("http://www.example.com/file.txt", function(contents) {
    var my_number = document.getElementById("my_input").value;
    var hasString = contents.includes(my_number);
  }); to plain javacript

Comment: @Malasorte that won't fix problem

Comment: @Malasorte Perform the AJAX request with `XMLHttpRequest`. The function that sets the variables goes into the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function. Read an AJAX tutorial for the details.

Comment: Show where `my_function()` gets called. The submit issue is a bit trickier  than some other async issues

Comment: @charlietfl my_function() gets called inside <form action="some cgi script" onsubmit="return my_function()">

Comment: Try use: $.getScript("path"+filenum+".txt").done() , call the file and execute as javascript... if you can change to .js extension like done this. before this you can add inside the done a function callback to run/call your script for this instance

Answer (score 0):

`hasString` is a local variable of the callback function provided to `$.get` as second argument. This is why it's undefined outside said function. Note just moving the variable declaration to the outer scope won't fix the problem, as the callback function will be executed after the check `hasString == false` anyway (it will be executed when the get request finishes).

Answering your question more directly: either perform the get request synchronously (and properly declare the variable in the scope you need to use it) or restructure your code to use the information retrieved by the get request only inside the callback. Read [the post @abc123 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for more information.